# setting fields values from multiple joins in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have 3 models:

```
public class Job
{
    public string CustomerRef {get;set;}
    public string AddressRef {get;set;}
    public string JobStatusRef {get;set;}
    public string CustomerName {get;set;}
    public string AddressTown {get;set;}
    public string JobStatusName {get;set;}
}

public class JobStatus
{
    public string JobStatusRef {get;set;}
    public string JobStatusName {get;set;}
}

public class Customer
{
    public string CustomerRef {get;set;}
    public string AddressTown {get;set;}
}
```

All these Models are populated into List objects.

I want to have a method that returns a list with the fields:

```
CustomerName;
AddressTown;
JobStatusName;
```

set with values from the other 2 List objects

I created this join:

```
var query_join4 = from j in Data
                  join js in JobStatus.Data
                  on j.JobStatusRef equals js.JobStatusRef
                  join c in Customer.Data
                  on j.CustomerRef equals c.CustomerRef
                  select new
                  {
                     //what goes here??
                  };
```

This method has to return a type of List

I have played around but with no success...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you're extremely close. Assuming the rest of the query is okay, you should be able to create an anonymous type by selecting the fields you want, like this:

```
var query_join4 = from j in Data
                  join js in JobStatus.Data
                  on j.JobStatusRef equals js.JobStatusRef
                  join c in Customer.Data
                  on j.CustomerRef equals c.CustomerRef
                  select new
                  {
                      j.CustomerName,
                      c.AddressTown,
                      js.JobStatusName
                  };
```

If you need to pass this around to use it elsewhere in your program, you'll probably want to create a separate class to store those values.

```
public class CustomerResult
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string AddressTown { get; set; }
    public string JobStatusName { get; set; }
}

...

select new CustomerResult
{
    CustomerName = j.CustomerName,
    AddressTown = c.AddressTown,
    JobStatusName = js.JobStatusName
}
```

If you want to just return a `List<Job>`, then use that class instead of a new one.

```
select new Job
{
    CustomerName = j.CustomerName,
    AddressTown = c.AddressTown,
    JobStatusName = js.JobStatusName

    // you may want to add the other fields too so your Job class is fully populated
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. I should have stated clearer on my question which I will do so in a minute) that the method has to return a type of List<Job>